# How do I split a string and use it as function arguments in Go?

Tags: go

I have a string that is separated by spaces, in this example, its a command: `ls -al`.

Go has a method `exec.Command` that needs to accept this command as multiple arguments, I call it like so: `exec.Command("ls", "-al")`

Is there a way to take a arbitrary string, split it by spaces, and pass all of its values as arguments to the method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass any `[]T` as a parameter of type `...T` using `foo...` where foo is of type `[]T`: [spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters)

exec.Command is of type:

```
func Command(name string, arg ...string) *Cmd
```

In this case you will have to pass 1st argument (name) directly and you can expand the rest with ...:

```
args := strings.Fields(mystr) //or any similar split function
exec.Command(args[0], args[1:]...)
```

Comment: This doesn't deal with quoted portions of the input string

Answer (score 4):

I recently discovered a nice package that handles splitting strings exactly as the shell would, including handling quotes, etc: https://github.com/kballard/go-shellquote

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, every other answer here is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer the first part of your question — see [strings.Fields](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Fields).

Comment: Thanks, haha. Now I just need to pass it along :)

Comment: This won't work with quoted arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Yep. An example:

```
func main() {
    arguments := "arg1 arg2 arg3"

    split := strings.Split(arguments, " ")

    print(split...)
}

func print(args...string) {
    fmt.Println(args)
}
```

Comment: This won't work if the arguments contain spaces (either because they are quoted or the spaces are escaped).